# Converting a <V:shape>/Embed to a w:drawing

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have a `V:Shape` that I am assuming has come from the conversion of a .Doc file to a .Docx file, but in the code I have written, I am wanting a `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Pictures.Picture`.

Is there any way to programically convert to a `Picture`?

The snippet I'm using is:

```
 foreach (var item in value)
 {
   if (!item.Descendants<Picture>().Any()) //pictures are processed differently - they're an absolute s**t storm to code...
   {
     p.Append(item.CloneNode(true));
   }
   else
   {
     p.Append(CreateImageRun(source, item, target, f));
   }
 }

public Run CreateImageRun(WordprocessingDocument sourceDoc, Run sourceRun, WordprocessingDocument target, FooterPart footerPart)
{
  ImagePart newPart = footerPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Png);

  ImageData shape = sourceRun.Descendants<ImageData>().FirstOrDefault();

  ImagePart p = sourceDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetPartById(shape.RelationshipId) as ImagePart;

  Bitmap image = new Bitmap(p.GetStream()); 

  using (Stream s = p.GetStream())
  {
    s.Position = 0;
    newPart.FeedData(s);
  }

  string partId = footerPart.GetIdOfPart(newPart);

  Drawing newImage = CreateImage(partId);

  return new Run(newImage);
}

private Drawing CreateImage(string relationshipId)
{
  // Define the reference of the image.
  return new Drawing(
                     new DW.Inline(
                         new DW.Extent() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L },
                         new DW.EffectExtent()
                         {
                             LeftEdge = 0L,
                             TopEdge = 0L,
                             RightEdge = 0L,
                             BottomEdge = 0L
                         },
                         new DW.DocProperties()
                         {
                             Id = (UInt32Value)1U,
                             Name = "Picture 1"
                         },
                         new DW.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
                             new A.GraphicFrameLocks() { NoChangeAspect = true }),
                         new A.Graphic(
                             new A.GraphicData(
                                 new PIC.Picture(
                                     new PIC.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                                         new PIC.NonVisualDrawingProperties()
                                         {
                                             Id = (UInt32Value)0U,
                                             Name = "New Bitmap Image.jpg"
                                         },
                                         new PIC.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),
                                     new PIC.BlipFill(
                                         new A.Blip(
                                             new A.BlipExtensionList(
                                                 new A.BlipExtension()
                                                 {
                                                     Uri =
                                                       "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}"
                                                 })
                                         )
                                         {
                                             Embed = relationshipId,
                                             CompressionState =
                                             A.BlipCompressionValues.Print
                                         },
                                         new A.Stretch(
                                             new A.FillRectangle())),
                                     new PIC.ShapeProperties(
                                         new A.Transform2D(
                                             new A.Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
                                             new A.Extents() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L }),
                                         new A.PresetGeometry(
                                             new A.AdjustValueList()
                                         ) { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle }))
                             ) { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" })
                     )
                     {
                         DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U,
                         DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U,
                         DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)0U,
                         DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)0U,
                         EditId = "50D07946"
                     });
        }
```

Full code context is in a different question here:

[Creating an ImagePart isn't saving the Relationship in OpenXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384826/creating-an-imagepart-isnt-saving-the-relationship-in-openxml/19435044?noredirect=1#comment29272655_19435044)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a quick/simple way to do this - and I should have worked it out earlier!

The `Shape` object has a `ImageData` object as a descendant, so I checked for that, and ran it through an extra method to get the `ImagePart`:

```
A.Blip pic = item.Descendants<A.Blip>().FirstOrDefault();

ImageData imageData = item.Descendants<ImageData>().FirstOrDefault();

if (pic == null && imageData == null) //pictures are processed differently - they're an absolute s**t storm to code...
{
  runToAmend.InsertAfterSelf(item.CloneNode(true));
}
else
{
  if(pic != null)
  {
    runToAmend.InsertAfterSelf(CreateImageFromBlip(source, item, footerHeaderPart,pic));
  }
  else if (imageData != null)
  {
    runToAmend.InsertAfterSelf(CreateImageFromShape(source, item, footerHeaderPart, imageData));
  }
}
```

Then created a new method - `CreateImageFromShape(..)` which then calls the original CreateImageRun.

```
private Run CreateImageFromShape(WordprocessingDocument sourceDoc, Run sourceRun, OpenXmlPart headerFooterPart, ImageData imageData)
{
  ImagePart p = sourceDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetPartById(imageData.RelationshipId) as ImagePart;

  return CreateImageRun(sourceDoc, sourceRun, headerFooterPart, p);
}
```

Job done.