# Converting a DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Vml.Shape to a Drawing and taking the positioning

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am converting a `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Vml.Shape` to a `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Drawing` as I am merging from one document to another.

Is there a simple way to take the positioning information? At current it's in a `Style` attrib.

***Standard CreateImage(...) method taken from the internets***

```
using A = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;
using DW = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Wordprocessing;
using PIC = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Pictures;

 private Drawing CreateImage(string relationshipId)
        {
            // Define the reference of the image.
            return new Drawing(
                     new DW.Inline(
                         new DW.Extent() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L },
                         new DW.EffectExtent()
                         {
                             LeftEdge = 0L,
                             TopEdge = 0L,
                             RightEdge = 0L,
                             BottomEdge = 0L
                         },
                         new DW.DocProperties()
                         {
                             Id = (UInt32Value)1U,
                             Name = "Picture 1"
                         },
                         new DW.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
                             new A.GraphicFrameLocks() { NoChangeAspect = true }),
                         new A.Graphic(
                             new A.GraphicData(
                                 new PIC.Picture(
                                     new PIC.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                                         new PIC.NonVisualDrawingProperties()
                                         {
                                             Id = (UInt32Value)0U,
                                             Name = "New Bitmap Image.jpg"
                                         },
                                         new PIC.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),
                                     new PIC.BlipFill(
                                         new A.Blip(
                                             new A.BlipExtensionList(
                                                 new A.BlipExtension()
                                                 {
                                                     Uri =
                                                       "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}"
                                                 })
                                         )
                                         {
                                             Embed = relationshipId,
                                             CompressionState =
                                             A.BlipCompressionValues.Print
                                         },
                                         new A.Stretch(
                                             new A.FillRectangle())),
                                     new PIC.ShapeProperties(
                                         new A.Transform2D(
                                             new A.Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
                                             new A.Extents() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L }),
                                         new A.PresetGeometry(
                                             new A.AdjustValueList()
                                         ) { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle }))
                             ) { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" })
                     )
                     {
                         DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U,
                         DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U,
                         DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)0U,
                         DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)0U,
                         EditId = "50D07946"
                     });
        }
```

Comment: I have similar problem while parsing the DOCX files. I even referred your other SO questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712900/converting-a-vshape-embed-to-a-wdrawing for the same but some how I am unable find the solution. Please find my  SO question for details : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51502564/unable-to-read-shapes-from-docx-file-using-openxmlsdk . I appreciate any help on this regard.